# In Angular / HTML, how to show icons on mouseover in a table

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have my own Icon component so it's not a normal html img-src or a fa fa-icon. 
I must use this component. (And I also can't use Bootstrap or anything like this.)

So my question is:

I have a table, and in the last column if I hover over the cell, 3 small icons should appear, and when my mouse leaves the cell, they should disappear.

I though that I could solve this with a div and *ngIf="(mouseOver)"  or something like this but it doesn't work.

Is there any solution to this?

(I can't show code because of my company)

Comment: Some code is understandably unshareable due to it being the property of a company, however you should be able to create a minimal, reproduceable example of where you're up to and the problem you are facing without sharing any protected code.

Comment: @Tom okay so here is some code I can show you, this is the last coloumn of the table, where on the right side of the cell there is the last login date (its atable about users) and on the right there are my-icons.

Comment: @Tom     <td>
        <span class="left">
          {{
            item.lastLoginDate
              ? (item.lastLoginDate | fromnow)
              : ('USER_MANAGEMENT.UNKNOWN_LAST_LOGIN' | translate)
          }}
        </span>
        <span class="right" *ngIf="(mouseOver)">
          <my-icon [icon]="Icon.edit"></m3d-icon>
          <my-icon [icon]="Icon.password"></m3d-icon>
          <my-icon [icon]="Icon.delete"></m3d-icon>
        </span>
      </td>
Obviously that (mouseover) part is not correct but I would like something like this.

Comment: @kameholic1582 Please consider editing your post to include the code that you've pasted as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it, apparently only in css like this:

```
div span.only-show-on-hover {
  visibility: hidden;
  float: right;
}
div:hover span.only-show-on-hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Thank you for your answers, I don't know why I didn't find this solution earlier.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div (mouseenter) ="mouseEnter() "  (mouseleave) ="mouseLeave()">
        HOVER ME!
        <h1 [hidden]="!iconVisible">ICON</h1>
 </div>
```

And the Component:

```
mouseEnter() {
  console.log("mouse enter");
  this.iconVisible = true;
}

mouseLeave() {
  console.log("mouse leave");
  this.iconVisible = false;
}
```

Try it in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brandtCodes/rubeLjy7/7/).

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to set the color of the icons to transparent and add a css hover in which you change it to a visible color. The hover should be added to the td. Since I cant see your code I cannot be more specific but there's no need for angular code for this.

You can set visibility:hidden and visibility:visible for those icon. I assume you want them to appear if the cursor is above the td. I'd create a wrapper around them like:

html:

```
<td>
   <div class="wrapper">
    icons..
   </div>
</td>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.wrapper:hover{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: They are not normal icons, they are exported from Inkscape so I can't manually change the color. I put some code in the other comment. That's all I have now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseenter and mouseleave with passing the event as a parameter to fire the current element.

HTML :

```
<div>
   <my-icon (mouseenter)="showMyIcons($event) (mouseenter)="hideMyIcons($event)"></my-icon>
</div>
```

TS :

```
showMyIcons(event) {
   event.target.classList.remove('hidden')
}

hideMyIcons(event) {
   event.target.classList.add('hidden')
}
```

CSS :

```
.hidden {
   opacity:0;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```